# File not found error on User control on production

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

I made 2 usercontrols for sharepoint 2007 site. Everything  is working fine on test server. I  deployed it on production but only 1 got deployed and placed properly. The second user control is added n deployed to web part galleries but gives File not found error when i add it on web part page. I deployed it using WSP. yet it gives this error. I checked logs it did not show anything. I have no idea what to do. please help. If more details are required I am ready to share but please help me
![Error which I get] https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOjwb.jpg

Comment: Since you developed it. Check if you have included everything in the wsp. manually check if the wsp have deployed all the required files.

Comment: I check the web.config & safe control entry  it is right. Where else shall I check?

Comment: I meant.. check for files... you said user controls so I assume they should be desployed in CONTROLTEMPLATES folder, if so check those. WSP deploys files where you ask it to deploy :) so you will have to know which files to deploy where. Also logs and event logs should give you something.

Comment: No clue in event viewer and event logs. User control is also present in control template

Answer (score 0):

WSP will deploy according to your requirements. You could build your WSPs automatically using WSPBuilder http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/

You should not deploy the user controls to web part galleries. The user controls should be deployed to CONTROLTEMPLATES so modify your WSP accordingly.

You could use the SmartPart to show any controls you developed.
http://smartpart.codeplex.com/